# How to instll Siesta Lite on windows 8

Tags: automation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, automated-tests, siesta

We are implementing a project where we need to develop applications in sencha touch and as a tester i will be responsible to test these applications. After some research, I found out that Bryntum's Siesta is the best tool to automate the Manual test cases.

Before we decide to get the license, i just wanted to goof around it a bit so I downloaded the Lite version but I am not able to figure out how to install it on my Windows 8 machine. There isn't any .exe file in the downloaded folder when i extracted it.

Can anyone help me out with this please!

Thanks Already!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to install really, since Siesta is just a web based tool (pure HTML, JS and CSS). Just extract into a web server and visit /examples and it will work. Getting started guide here: http://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/#!/guide/siesta_getting_started